# How to Create an Entity Framework Built in Function to Convert of the Sql Server

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Like described in [Dixin's Blog](https://weblogs.asp.net/Dixin/EntityFramework.Functions#Built-in_function)

I'm trying to create this built in function:

```
public static class BuiltInFunctions
{
    [Function(FunctionType.BuiltInFunction, "CONVERT")]
    public static string ConvertToInt(this string type, string value) => Function.CallNotSupported<string>();
}
```

And I'm using it like:

```
Query().Where(x => "int".ConvertToInt(x.MyNVarcharColumn) ...
```

But the SQL generated is like:

```
SELECT [columns] FROM [table] WHERE (CONVERT(N'int', 'ValueOfMyNVarcharColumn')) ...
```

When I was expected something like

```
SELECT [columns] FROM [table] WHERE (CONVERT(int, MyNVarcharColumn)) ...
```

or

```
SELECT [columns] FROM [table] WHERE (CONVERT(int, 'ValueOfMyNVarcharColumn')) ...
```

What can I do to get the expected result?

The important here is known how to generate the typename parameters to SQL native functions.

Comment: Did you solved it? I'm facing exactly same issue...

Comment: Sorry ... I don't have a solution for this. I changed my column type to work.